# How to send and receive an ajax request with jQuery?

Tags: java, jquery

I am new to jQuery and am having trouble following the documentation. I have a variable in JavaScript (that I already obtained from an html form) that I would like to send using AJAX to the server.  I want to the server to do whatever it needs to do with that value and then reply with either "success" or "failure" (I know how to do the backend part).  How do I send the request and then receive the reply with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the request you use the $.post or $.get function (or the $.ajax function if you want loads of control)

```
$.post('example.com/script', {
    'param1':somaVar
 }, function(data){
    alert(data); //data is whatever the server returned
 });
```

For both $.get and $.post the argument order is like this: (url, [data], [callback], [type]). Url is the url to which the request is done, data is the data with which the request is send, callback is a function that is executed when the request is complete. Type is the type of data the server will return (jQuery usually finds this out on itself) possibles are "xml", "html", "script", "json", "jsonp", or "text"